# Is there a way to get all documents in a subcollection (Firestore)

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I'm having difficulties querying all documents inside a subcollection in my Firestore database. (I am using Node.js)

My goal is to get all the data from every document inside the subcollection named `favorites`

My database structure looks like this.
[image: firestore db stucture]

I looked at the documentation at https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data but without any result how to solve the problem.

**My query looks like this right now:**

```
exports.getAllFavoritePodcasts = (req, res) => {
  db.collection('users')
    .doc(req.user.userId)
    .collection('favorites')
    .then(snapshot => {
      snapshot.forEach(doc => {
        console.log(doc.id, '=>', doc.data());
      });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log('Error getting documents', err);
    });
}
```

But I get `TypeError: db.collection(...).doc(...).collection(...).then is not a function`

Comment: I'm not familiar with firebase but aren't you missing `.get()` before `then` -> `db.collection(...).doc(...).collection(...).get().then`

Comment: That solved my problem. Thank you so much @Molda :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To summarize, **get()** method has to be called to retrieve the results. It can also be found in this [**example**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_all_documents_in_a_collection) of getting all documents in a collection, in the Cloud Firebase article you have mentioned.

Answer (score 15):

### With Firebase Version 9 (Jan, 2022 Update):

If **subcollection(subcoll)** contains **3 documents(doc1, doc2, doc3)** like below:

```
coll > doc > subcoll > doc1 > field1: "value1", field2: "value2"
                       doc2 > field1: "value1", field2: "value2"
                       doc3 > field1: "v1",     field2: "v2"
```

You can get **all 3 documents(doc1, doc2, doc3) of subcollection(subcoll)** with the code below:

```js
import { getDocs, collection } from "firebase/firestore";

const docsSnap = await getDocs(collection(db,"coll/doc/subcoll"));
      
docsSnap.forEach((doc) => {
  console.log(doc.data()); // "doc1", "doc2" and "doc3"
});
```

Without **forEach() method** to get **all 3 documents(doc1, doc2, doc3) of subcollection(subcoll)** below:

```js
import { getDocs, collection } from "firebase/firestore";

const docsSnap = await getDocs(collection(db, "coll/doc/subcoll"));
        
console.log(docsSnap.docs[0].data()); // "doc1"
console.log(docsSnap.docs[1].data()); // "doc2"
console.log(docsSnap.docs[2].data()); // "doc3"
```

In addition, you can get **2 documents(doc1, doc2) of subcollection(subcoll)** with **while** below:

```js
import { query, collection, where, getDocs } from "firebase/firestore";

const q = query(collection(db, "coll/doc/subcoll"), 
                where("field1", "==", "value1"));
    
const docsSnap = await getDocs(q);

docsSnap.forEach((doc) => {
  console.log(doc.data()); // "doc1" and "doc2"
});
```

Without **forEach() method** to get **2 documents(doc1, doc2) of subcollection(subcoll)** with **while** below:

```js
import { query, collection, where, getDocs } from "firebase/firestore";

const q = query(collection(db, "coll/doc/subcoll"),
                where("field1", "==", "value1"));
    
const docsSnap = await getDocs(q);
    
console.log(docsSnap.docs[0].data()); // "doc1"
console.log(docsSnap.docs[1].data()); // "doc2"
```

Again, in addition, you can get **only one specific document(doc3) of subcollection(subcoll)** with the code below:

```js
import { getDoc, doc } from "firebase/firestore";

const docSnap = await getDoc(doc(db, "coll/doc/subcoll/doc3"));
          
console.log(docSnap.data()); // "doc3"
```