# how to access firestore subcollection using cloud functions

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

i have the following database model:
car Workshops collection which is the root collections, and it has collections based on car Brands for example
car Workshops ==> KIA(collection) and KIA collection have some fields and another sub collections called workshops

as following
car Workshops ==> Kia (collection) ==> workshops

so i wants my code to return the wokrshops which is inside kia collection

screenshots of my database

[image]

Comment: There's nothing special about doing this in Cloud Functions. Did you try anything yet? If not, this might be a good place to look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58656602/is-there-a-way-to-get-all-documents-in-a-subcollection-firestore

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen yes I have manged to do it, nothing special in doing it in cloud function i know, but I have to make it with cloud function because I use this data in more complex. Operations  with cloud functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

U can use collection group query with specified document id. Try this, its work for me.
[CollectionGroupQuery but limit search to subcollections under a particular document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68049541/collectiongroupquery-but-limit-search-to-subcollections-under-a-particular-docum/68049847#68049847)